# How to declare a constant "mutable pointer" to an immutable block of memory

Tags: c, c99, const-correctness

I'm wondering how to declare, basically, `(a const pointer to (a mutable pointer to (a const type)))` in C99.

Let's say I have this call site:

```
const uint8_t* result;
create(&result);
```

Is `void create(const uint8_t * const * resultPtr)` the correct way to declare the callee in this case or does it mean something unintended? I don't need to reassign `resultPtr` and the caller shouldn't mess with [from this perspective] `*resultPtr[0]` but my function needs to assign `*resultPtr = …`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's ask [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=declare%20p%20as%20const%20pointer%20to%20pointer%20to%20const%20char):

```
$ cdecl declare p as const pointer to pointer to const char
const char ** const p
```

This declaration can be read entirely from right to left to obtain the English version (remembering that `const char` and `char const` are the same).

Comment: Ooh, I had forgotten all about cdecl. Thanks much!

Comment: Sadly, the `cdecl` site seems to have gone the way of all things. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Some rules of thumb:

- `<type> * const <varName> = <value>` always creates an immutable pointer `<varName>` towards a `<type>` content. Please consider the `const` on thright side of the asteriks `* const`.
- all these options create immutable contents:

  - `const <type> <pointers> <varName> = <value>`
  - `<type> const <pointers> <varName> = <value>`
  - `const <type> const <pointers> <varName> = <value>`
  - `<type> const const <pointers> <varName> = <value>`

Caveat: The last two options return a

> warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]

on the Clang compiler and should be considered as bad practice.

So to have an immutable pointer to a mutable pointer to an immutable `uint8_t` all these options work:

- `const uint8_t * * const result = NULL`
- `uint8_t const * * const result = NULL`
- `const uint8_t const * * const result = NULL`
- `uint8_t const const * * const result = NULL`

However, the second option

```c
uint8_t const * * const result = NULL;
```

seems to be the most readable and canonical way to write it IMHO. You may find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60105119/4999991) also informative in this regard.