# If char*s are read only, why can I overwrite them?

Tags: arrays, c, c-strings, string-literals

My course taught me that char*s are static/read only so I thought that would mean you can't edit them after you have defined them. But when I run:

```
char* fruit = "banana";
printf("fruit is %s\n", fruit);
fruit = "apple";
printf("fruit is %s\n", fruit);
```

Then it compiles fine and gives me:

```
fruit is banana
fruit is apple
```

Why? Have I misunderstood what it means to be read-only? Sorry if this is obvious but I'm new to coding and I can't find the answer online.

Comment: You haven't overwritten anything. You just pointed `fruit` at a different string.

Comment: try `const char * const fruit = "banana";`

Comment: A `char*` is not read-only. A string literal like `"banana"` or `"apple"` is read-only. C allows `char*` to point to a string literal.

Comment: right ok - so it's read-only because I can't actually change 'banana' , I can just reallocate the pointer to some string somewhere else in memory?

Comment: There's no reallocation happening. Both `"banana"` and `"apple"` are already allocated in static memory when the program starts. All you're doing is changing the value of `fruit` to be the address of where `"apple"` is stored.

Comment: `char *fruit = "banana"` is read only memory, it just has "banana" in the read-only parts of the memory. making fruit a pointer to that makes any writing operation on this memory illegal.

Comment: @sally2000, think of it this way, when you declare a pointer and initialize it to point to `"banna"`, you initialize the pointer to point to the address of the first letter `'b'`. (e.g. in `char* fruit = "banana";`). `fruit` (a pointer) just holds the *address of* `'b'` as its *value*. When you assign `fruit = "apple";`, you are simply changing the value held by `fruit` to the *address of* `'a'`. So now `fruit` *points to* the `'a'` in `"apple"` (which allows access to `"apple"` as a *string*)

Comment: To round out the excellent group of answers and comments, just be aware of an additional way to initialize `char *fruit` so that it DOES point to a modifiable array in memory. You can use a *compound literal* to initialize `fruit` to point to the modifiable `"banana"` using `char *fruit = (char []){ "banana" };` Here the *compound literal* (or *compound initializer*) is simply a *cast-to-type* prior to the string `"banana"`. It is available in C99 and later (and provided as an extension by some for earlier language standards)

Comment: C does not have a concept of "read-only memory". All guarantees are given by the programmer and it is his responsibility not to break this contract. For typical declarations, the compiler will report a diagnostic message, but there are ways to break the contract without. And a `char *` is a pointer which can be modified (no guarantees by the programmer).

Comment: As a sidenote: If you have questions regarding what was taught, you should first talk to your teacher/tutor. He best should know what he wanted to say. As there are a lot of bad teachers around, a good C book as backup is strongly recommended, too.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The presented code snippet does not change the string literals themselves. It only changes the values stored in the pointer `fruit`.

You can imagine these lines

```
char* fruit = "banana";
fruit = "apple";
```

the following way

```
char unnamed_static_array_banana[] = { 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', '\0' };
char *fruit = &unnamed_static_array_banana[0];
char unnamed_static_array_apple[]  = { 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', '\0' };
fruit = &unnamed_static_array_apple[0];
```

These statements do not change the arrays that correspond to the string literals.

On the other hand if you will try to write

```
char* fruit = "banana";
printf("fruit is %s\n", fruit);
fruit[0] = 'h';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
printf("fruit is %s\n", fruit);
```

that is if you will try to change a string literal using a pointer that points to it (to the first character of the string literal) then the program will have undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
> elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
> modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: mm ok but if i use char[] instead e.g. fruit [10] = {'a','p','p','l','e','\0'} is fruit here not also just a pointer to the memory address of 'a'? how come I can change char[] but not char*?

Comment: @sally2000 If you are using a character array instead of a string literal and have a pointer to the first character of the character array then you may change it provided thatf the array is not declared with qualifier const.

Comment: @sally2000 Internally string literals are stored as arrays with the static storage duration that may not be changed.

Comment: The string literal could be in read-only memory in some implementations (harvard-ish machines, or something running straight out of ROM, or a mmap-ed shared library on a modern protected mode system...) ... writing it would simply fail or even trigger a hardware exception... in other environments you would attempt and succeed...

Comment: @sally2000:  **NO**  If you have an array, `fruit` is not a pointer - it is an array.  Now it is true that if you use the name of an array, it will decay into a pointer to char, but it *is* an array.  For instance if you write `char  fruit [10] = {'a','p','p','l','e','\0'};` you can't then write `fruit = "banana";`.  You will also find that `sizeof(fruit);` is 10, not `sizeof(char*)` (which is probably 4 or 8).

Answer (score 10):

In your program, the expression `"banana"` denotes a string literal object in the program image, a character array. The value of the expression is of type `char *`, or "pointer to character". The pointer points to the first byte of that array, the character `'b'`.

Your `char *fruit` variable also has type "pointer to character" and takes its initial value from this expression: it is initialized to a copy of the pointer to the data, not the data itself; it merely points to the `b`.

When you assign `"apple"` to `fruit`, you're just replacing its pointer value with another one, so it now points to a different literal array.

To modify the data itself, you need an expression such as:

```
char *fruit = "banana";
fruit[0] = 'z';  /* try to turn "banana" into "zanana" */
```

According to the ISO C standard, the behavior of this is not defined. It **could** be that the `"banana"` array is read-only, but that is not required.

C implementations can make string literals writable, or make it an option.

(If you are able to modify a string literal, that doesn't mean that all is well.  Firstly, your program is still not well defined according to ISO C: it is not portable. Secondly, the C compiler is allowed to merge literals which have common content into the same storage. This means that two occurrences of `"banana"` in the program could in fact be exactly the same array. Furthermore, the string literal `"nana"` occurring somewhere in the program could be the suffix of the array `"banana"` occurring elsewhere; in other words, share the same storage. Modifying a literal can have surprising effects; the modification can appear in other literals.)

Also "static" and "read-only" aren't synonymous. Most static storage in C is in fact modifiable. We can create a modifiable static character array which holds a string like this:

```
/* at file scope, i.e. outside of any function */
char fruit[] = "banana";
```

Or:

```
{
  /* in a function */
  static fruit[] = "banana";
```

If we leave out the array size, it is automatically sized from the initializing string literal, and includes space for the null terminating byte. In the function, we need `static` to put the array into static storage, otherwise we get a local variable.

These arrays can be modified; `fruit[0] = 'z'` is well-defined behavior.

Also, in these situations, `"banana"` doesn't denote a character array. The array is the variable `fruit`; the `"banana"` expression is just a piece of syntax which indicates the array's initial value:

```
char *fruit = "banana";  // "banana" is an object in program image
                         // initial value is a pointer to that object

char fruit_array[] = "apple"; // "apple" is syntax giving initial value
```

Answer (score 6):

The `fruit` object is writable - it can be set to point to a different string literal.

The *string literals* `"banana"` and `"apple"` are not writable.  You can modify `fruit` to point to a string literal, but if you do so then you should not attempt to modify the thing that `fruit` *points to*:

```
char *fruit = "banana"; // fruit points to first character of string literal
fruit = "apple";        // okay, fruit points to first character of different string literal
*fruit = 'A';           // not okay, attempting to modify contents of string literal
fruit[1] = 'P';         // not okay, attempting to modify contents of string literal
```

Attempting to modify the contents of a string literal results in undefined behavior - your code may work as expected, or you may get a runtime error, or something completely unexpected may happen.  For safety's sake, if you're defining a variable to point to a string literal, you should declare it `const`:

```
const char *fruit = "banana";  // can also be written char const *
```

You can still assign `fruit` to point to different strings:

```
fruit = "apple";
```

but if you try to modify what `fruit` points to, the compiler will yell at you.

If you want to define a pointer that can only point to one specific string literal, then you can `const`-qualify the pointer as well:

```
const char * const fruit = "banana"; // can also be written char const * const
```

This way, if you try to either write to what `fruit` points to, or try to set `fruit` to point to a different object, the compiler will yell at you.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, when you perform

```
char* fruit = "banana";
```

You set up a pointer `fruit` to the first letter of "banana". When printing it out, C basically starts at the 'b' and keeps printing letters until it hits a `\0` null character at the end.

By then saying

```
fruit = "apple";
```

You've changed the pointer `fruit` to now point to the first letter of "apple"

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `char*` aren't read-only.  `char * const`s are. And they are different from `char const *`.  And literal strings (e.g., "banana") should be, but aren't necessarily.

```
char * const  cpfruit = "banana";
cpfruit = "apple";        // error

char const * cpfruit = "banana";
cpfruit[0] = 'x';        // error

char * ncfruit = "banana";
ncfruit[0] = 'x';        // compile will allow, but may cause run-time error.
```

Answer (score 3):

when defining a C string, aka `char` array, by double quotations `"..."`, in the format below:

```
char * <varName> = "<someString>"
```

only the elements of the array are immutable (their content can not be changed). In other words, the `<varName>` has a `const char *` type (a mutable pointer towards a read-only memory). And every time you invoke the assignment operator with double quotations `<varName> = "<otherString>"` it changes the pointer value automatically. The below example should give a complete overview of the different possibilities:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char * var_1 = "Lorem";
    printf("1. %s , %p\n", var_1, var_1); // --> 1. Lorem , 0x400640

    var_1 = "ipsu";
    printf("2. %s , %p\n", var_1, var_1); // --> 2. ipsu , 0x400652

    // var_1[0] = 'x'; // --> Segmentation fault

    var_1++;
    printf("3. %s , %p\n", var_1, var_1); // --> 3. psu , 0x400653

    char var_2[] = {'L', 'o', 'r', 'e', 'm', '\0'};
    printf("4. %s , %p\n", var_2, var_2); // --> 4. Lorem , 0x7ffed0fc5381

    var_2[0] = 'x';
    printf("5. %s , %p\n", var_2, var_2); // --> 5. xorem , 0x7ffed0fc5381

    // var_2++; //error: lvalue required as increment operand

    char var_3[] = "Lorem";
    printf("6. %s , %p\n", var_3, var_3); // --> 6. Lorem , 0x7ffe36a42d5c

    // var_3 = "ipsu"; // --> error: assignment to expression with array type

    var_3[0] = 'x';
    printf("7. %s , %p\n", var_3, var_3); // --> 7. xorem , 0x7ffe36a42d5c

    char * const var_4 = "Lorem";

    // var_4 = "ipsu"; // --> error: assignment of read-only variable

    // var_4[0] = 'x'; // --> Segmentation fault

    char const * var_5 = "Lorem";
    printf("8. %s , %p\n", var_5, var_5); // --> Lorem , 0x400720

    var_5 = "ipsu";
    printf("9. %s , %p\n", var_5, var_5); // --> ipsu , 0x400732

    // var_5[0] = 'x'; // --> error: assignment of read-only location

    const char * var_6 = "Lorem";
    printf("10. %s , %p\n", var_6, var_6); // --> 10. Lorem , 0x400760

    var_6 = "ipsu";
    printf("11. %s , %p\n", var_6, var_6); // --> 11. ipsu , 0x400772

    // var_6[0] = 'x'; // --> error: assignment of read-only location

    const char const * var_7 = "Lorem"; // clang only --> warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
    printf("12. %s , %p\n", var_7, var_7); // --> 12. Lorem , 0x400760

    var_7 = "ipsu";
    printf("13. %s , %p\n", var_7, var_7); // --> 13. ipsu , 0x400772

    // var_7[0] = 'x'; // --> error: assignment of read-only location

    char const const * var_8 = "Lorem"; // clang only --> warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
    printf("14. %s , %p\n", var_8, var_8); // --> 14. Lorem , 0x400790

    var_8 = "ipsu";
    printf("15. %s , %p\n", var_8, var_8); // --> 15. ipsu , 0x4007a2

    // var_8[0] = 'x'; // --> error: assignment of read-only location

    char const * const var_9 = "Lorem";

    // var_9 = "ipsu"; // --> error: assignment of read-only variable

    // var_9[0] = 'x'; // --> error: assignment of read-only location

    const char var_10[] = {'L', 'o', 'r', 'e', 'm', '\0'};

    // var_10[0] = 'x'; // --> error: assignment of read-only location

    // var_10++; // --> error: lvalue required as increment operand

    char const var_11[] = {'L', 'o', 'r', 'e', 'm', '\0'};

    // var_11[0] = 'x'; // --> error: assignment of read-only location 

    // var_11++; // --> error: lvalue required as increment operand

    const char var_12[] = "Lorem";

    // var_12[0] = 'x'; // --> error: assignment of read-only location

    // var_12++; // --> error: lvalue required as increment operand

    char const var_13[] = "Lorem";

    // var_13[0] = 'x'; // --> error: assignment of read-only location

    // var_13++; // --> error: lvalue required as increment operand


    return 0;
}
```

this code was tested on GCC, Clang and Visual Studio.

Basically, there are three possibilities:

- immutable pointer, mutable content

  - `char <varName>[] = {'L', 'o', 'r', 'e', 'm', '\0'};`
  - `char <varName>[] = "Lorem";`
- mutable pointer, immutable content

  - `char * <varName> = "Lorem";`
  - `char const * <varName> = "Lorem";`
  - `const char * <varName> = "Lorem";`
  - `const char const * <varName> = "Lorem";`
  - `char const const * <varName> = "Lorem";`
- immutable pointer, immutable content

  - `char * const <varName> = "Lorem";`
  - `char const * const <varName> = "Lorem";`
  - `const char * const <varName> = "Lorem";`
  - `const char <varName>[] = {'L', 'o', 'r', 'e', 'm', '\0'};`
  - `char const <varName>[] = {'L', 'o', 'r', 'e', 'm', '\0'};`
  - `const char <varName>[] = "Lorem";`
  - `char const <varName>[] = "Lorem";`

### Conclusion:

- `<typing> <varName>[] = <string>` always returns an immutable pointer and the mutability of the content is independant from the `<array>` format (`"Lorem"` or `{'L', 'o', 'r', 'e', 'm', '\0'}`)
- `<typing> * <varName> = "someString"` always returns immutable content
- `<typing> * const <varName> = "someString"` always returns both immutable content and pointer
- `char const <other>`, `char const <other>`, `const char const <other>`, and `char const const <other>` always create immutable content.

I have tried to summerise C's array behavior [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/ezm02g/understanding_c_arrays_correct_syntax/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) in detail.

Answer (score 2):

What your course has taught you is correct!

When you defined `char* fruit = "banana"` in the first place you basically have `fruit` as a pointer to a *constant character* . The 7 bytes (including the null termination) of the string resides in the `.ro` section of the object file (section name would obviously vary depending on the platform).

When you reset the char pointer fruit to "apple" it just pointed to another memory location in the read only section which contains "apple"

Essentially when you say fruit is a *constant* it refers to `fruit` being a pointer to a `const` memory. If you would have defined it as a `const pointer to a const string` :-
`char* const fruit = "banana";`
 The compiler would have stopped you from resetting it to "apple"

Comment: "fruit as a pointer to a constant character "  --> Disagree.  [@rackandboneman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44294649/if-chars-are-read-only-why-can-i-overwrite-them#comment75598188_44294690) comment says it well.  `fruit` is a `char *`.  With its original value, attempting to change what it points to is UB.

Answer (score 2):

You are pointing your variable `fruit` to a different string. You are only overwriting the address (location). The compiler will see your constant string "banana" and "apple" and store them separately in program memory. Let's say the string "banana" goes to memory cell located at address `1` and "apple" gets stored to memory addesss `2`. Now when you do:

```
fruit = "banana";
```

the compiler will just assign `1` to variable `fruit`, which means it points to address `1` which containts the string `banana`. When you do:

```
fruit = "apple";
```

the compiler will assign `2` variable `fruit`, which means it points to addess `2` where the string `apple` is stored.

Comment: A nit, but the compiler will see the *string literals* `"banana"` and `"apple"` and provide storage for them in the `.rodata` (read-only data) section. (I think you are saying the same thing)

Comment: Yes, just wanted to keep it simple here.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `char *p="banana";` the string banana is stored in a read only memory location. Following which when you enter `p="apple";` the string apple is stored in some other memory location and the pointer is now pointing to the new memory location.

You can confirm this by printing `p` just after each assignment.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char *p = "Banana";
    printf("p contains address of string constant 'Banana' at 0x%p\n", p);

    p="Apple";
    printf("p contains address of string constant 'Apple' at 0x%p\n", p);

}
```

Comment: I think printing the address is a good idea to convince OP. I'd upvote your answer if it showed how it is done.

Comment: By the way, I do not know any standard that demands that string literals are put into read only memory. On some platforms this cannot even be enforced -- as there is not any MMU.

Comment: @hagello thanks for the edit. I have added the code showing the different address location but the formatting completely off. Will have to work on that. But hope it convinces the OP.

Comment: Your code doesn't demonstrate that string literals are stored in read-only memory. They almost certainly aren't stored literally in ROM (memory whose contents physically cannot be modified). They're likely to be stored in memory that's configured by the OS to be read-only.

Comment: You're printing the value of `p`, not the address of `p`.  The address of `p` would be `&p`.

Comment: @M.M I am printing the address location pointer p is pointing to. I wanted to prove that the data is not overwritten, the address location it is pointing to changes.

Comment: @SachinMathad "address location pointer p is pointing to" is different from "address of p" which you said in your answer.